# How to read entire sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sql

Please help me with following, I have a database which contain strings ( e.g. fotonames ).
And I want to read entire fotonames column into an arraylist. 
How can I do this?

Comment: http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-sqlite-database-in-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Cursor getfotoname() throws SQLException
{
 String getRT = "SELECT fotonames from "+ TABLE_NAME+";";
 Cursor mCur = sqldb.rawQuery(getRT, null);
 return mCur;
}
```

Now when you call

```
Cursor mCursor=null;

mCursor= DatabaseObject.getfotoname();

ArrayList<WhateverTypeYouWant> mArrayList = new ArrayList<WhateverTypeYouWant>();
for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); mCursor.moveToNext(); mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
// The Cursor is now set to the right position
mArrayList.add(mCursor.getWhateverTypeYouWant(WHATEVER_COLUMN_INDEX_YOU_WANT));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial will help you 
http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/

this is where you can lear how to fetch all values from one column
http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/3/#getrowasarray

or otherway is

fire query like this

```
 public Cursor columnValues() throws SQLException{
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Cursor mCursor = db.query(Course_Info_Table,
                              new String[] {Column1 , column2 },
                                            null,null, null, null, null);




                    //Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery("Select",null);
                    if (mCursor != null)
                    {
                    mCursor.moveToFirst();
                    }

                    return mCursor;



        }
```

and receive it like

```
    ArrayList<String> list1  = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> list12 = new ArrayList<String>();

cursor = dbm.columnValueofCourse();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

        String  reciv = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("column1"));

String      reciv3 = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("column2"));



            list1.add(reciv);
            list2.add(reciv3);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
```